# What's the difference between new Thing(param) and new(Thing(param))?

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator, coffeescript

I was writing some CoffeeScript just now, and getting a strange error:

`TypeError: Thing(param) is not a constructor`

But it is! And when I try it in the console:

```
var that = new Thing(param);
that.doesSomething();
```

After a bit of confusion, I looked through the compiled source and found out that `coffee` compiles `that = new Thing param` to `that = new(Thing(param));`. Weird; I've never seen that before. So I promptly try it: and tada! Now I can replicate:

```
var that = new(Thing(param));
that.previousLineErrorsOut();
```

(Incidentally, [the CoffeeScript generator on its home page](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) generates the `new Thing()` form. The plot thickens...)

I also try it out with native constructors (`new Worker("somefile")` and `new(Worker("somefile"))`), which behave "correctly", that is, there's no difference between the two forms.

So I'm thoroughly confused: what's `new()`? Why is it failing in some cases? **Why does CoffeeScript transform my perfectly fine `new` into `new()`?**

Comment: The CoffeeScript console at CoffeeScript.org is currently using CoffeeScript 1.1.2, the latest release version. If your local CoffeeScript installation is behaving differently, it must be a different version.

Comment: Nope. It is 1.1.2, straight off npm.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how the compiled JS on your system differs from the compiled JS in the Try CoffeeScript console, then?

Comment: This was actually a sneaky mistake in my code: there was non-breaking whitespace instead of a plain old space between the `new` and the `Thing`. Why this caused CS to misbehave I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` takes an expression representing a constructor and optionally a list of arguments enclosed in parentheses. For example:

```js
new Thing;   // equivalent to next line
new Thing(); // most common form
new (function() {})(); // calls the anonymous function as a
                       // constructor with no arguments
new (function() {});   // equivalent to previous; if no arguments are
                       // specified to new, it will call with no arguments
```

When you do this:

```js
new(Thing(param));
```

It's trying to run the result of calling `Thing` with the argument `param` as a constructor with no arguments. The parentheses after the `new` make `Thing(param)` the expression representing the constructor. As `Thing` does not return a constructor in your case, it fails. It's roughly equivalent to this:

```js
var clazz = Thing(param);
var instance = new clazz();
```

I do not know why CoffeeScript transforms it that way.

Comment: I wonder if there's a workaround... or will I just have to fork CS?

Comment: @FélixSaparelli: Unfortunately, I do not know a workaround. I don't have CoffeeScript installed (and I'd rather not install it just for this question) but you may want to make sure your installation is up to date.

Comment: Got it: `new(Thing)(param)`. So simple, yet so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the constructor-like call

```
new Thing(params)
```

and the function-like call

```
Thing(params)
```

is that in the 1st case the `this` keyword inside of the function body is bound to the object being created while in the 2nd case it's bound to the global object (a window in the browser)

The

```
new(Thing(params))
```

is a really strange form, and in this form the `Thing` is first called like a function, then its **result** is being tried agains the `new` word as a constructor without params.

It is extremely strange that your CS compiles it like that.

I tried it on he official site (http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/, the Try Coffeescript tab) and it compiles

```
that = new Thing param
```

to

```
var that;
that = new Thing(param);
```

Comment: It was mentioned in the question that the official site's version compiles like that. "(Incidentally, the CoffeeScript generator on its home page generates the new Thing() form. The plot thickens...)"